# How can I hide the 'to' field in the email sent by php mail

Tags: email-headers, php

- I am using php mail function to allow user to send me a mail from
  website.
- I am also allowing them to **"cc"** the email to themselves.

The whole purpose of making a **"send us message"** feature was not give our email to the users. But when the user selects the **"cc"** option, in the header of the mail that is sent to the user, the "to" field contains our primary email address.

How can I remove this, so that the users do not see our primary email address in the to field.

Comment: No what happens in bcc is that it still shows the to field, but not the bcc field. Since the cc option to the user is optional I can't put my email id in the bcc field, I have to keep it in the to field

Answer (score 1):

You could set the mailTo to an arbitrary mailbox at your domain "noreply@yourdomain.com" and add your company address in BCC?

But whatever reason you have for not exposing your email, imho it's quite unpolite :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the reason why I am not showing my email is not because I don't want to reveal it to them, but I don't want them to know that I am the moderator... Actually the people may know me, and I don't want to reveal that for the time being

Answer (score 0):

The e-mail message sent to  you must have a To: field to be delivered correctly. You could emulate the CC feature by sending to separate e-mail messages to the office and to the client.